# C++ LNK2019 Error, for V-ray programming

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, hyperlink, maya, lnk2019

```
1>plugman_s.lib(plugman.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@PEBD@Z) (referenced in function: "protected: class std::_Tree<class std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned __int64,class Plugin *,struct std::less<unsigned __int64>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,class Plugin *> >,0> >::iterator __cdecl std::_Tree<class std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned __int64,class Plugin *,struct std::less<unsigned __int64>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,class Plugin *> >,0> >::_Insert(bool,struct std::_Tree_nod<class std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned __int64,class Plugin *,struct std::less<unsigned __int64>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,class Plugin *> >,0> >::_Node *,struct std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,class Plugin *> const &)" (?_Insert@?$_Tree@V?$_Tmap_traits@_KPEAVPlugin@@U?$less@_K@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CB_KPEAVPlugin@@@std@@@3@$0A@@std@@@std@@IEAA?AViterator@12@_NPEAU_Node@?$_Tree_nod@V?$_Tmap_traits@_KPEAVPlugin@@U?$less@_K@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CB_KPEAVPlugin@@@std@@@3@$0A@@std@@@2@AEBU?$pair@$$CB_KPEAVPlugin@@@2@@Z))
1>plugman_s.lib(plugman.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (__imp_??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@XZ) (referenced in function: "protected: class std::_Tree<class std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned __int64,class Plugin *,struct std::less<unsigned __int64>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,class Plugin *> >,0> >::iterator __cdecl std::_Tree<class std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned __int64,class Plugin *,struct std::less<unsigned __int64>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,class Plugin *> >,0> >::_Insert(bool,struct std::_Tree_nod<class std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned __int64,class Plugin *,struct std::less<unsigned __int64>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,class Plugin *> >,0> >::_Node *,struct std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,class Plugin *> const &)" (?_Insert@?$_Tree@V?$_Tmap_traits@_KPEAVPlugin@@U?$less@_K@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CB_KPEAVPlugin@@@std@@@3@$0A@@std@@@std@@IEAA?AViterator@12@_NPEAU_Node@?$_Tree_nod@V?$_Tmap_traits@_KPEAVPlugin@@U?$less@_K@std@@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CB_KPEAVPlugin@@@std@@@3@$0A@@std@@@2@AEBU?$pair@$$CB_KPEAVPlugin@@@2@@Z) )
1>plugman_s.lib(plugman.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z) (referenced in function : "public: __cdecl std::logic_error::logic_error(class std::logic_error const &)" (??0logic_error@std@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z))
```

Hi everyone, I tried to solve this error during whole of my daytime but I couldn't. So I really want to your help.

I'll explain my problem. I want to compile some sample source code. The name is *Vray-Maya plug-in*, actually it's related with computer graphics programming. They already provided Visual Studio projects, so I just want to compile with this. The project finally generates some .dll file, actually it called *'Vray plugin'*.

That's my job. But I met this horrible link error.

As you can see, I think **plugman_s.lib** generates some problem. And I think this problem related with STL(because I could find *std::base_string* in my error message). Maybe **plugman_s.lib** uses some kinds of STL library, and when I made some dll library it makes some problem, but I'm not sure.

**plugman_s.lib** is published the company who provide *V-ray*, so I couldn't see source code of the library. It's not open. I also changed my VS project run-time library setting to **multi-thread debug dll(/MDd)** but it wasn't helpful.

I can't upload my source code because it's too big, but the source code was provided by company so I think there is no problem.

Here is the link about the Vray SDK development page. But, their explanation of compilation is not very detailed. So I couldn't solve the problem.

Could you give me some hint for solving this problem? And if you solve this problem, it will be really, really helpful for me.

My environment is WIN7, 64bit, VS2010.

(+ADD)

I'll attach the VS project, and Vray/Maya lib, include files.

[Vray VS Project(6.64KB)](http://vml.kaist.ac.kr/download/VrayVSProj.7z)
[Vray/Maya Lib&Include Files(13.7MB)](http://vml.kaist.ac.kr/download/VrayMayaResources.7z)

Actually I don't have idea which part of source code will be helpful to solve the problem.

So I just upload the project file. And also I upload the Vray/Maya include/lib files. I think those files are enough to compile the project. If you can do that, it will be really nice daylight for me.

Comment: Looks like a calling convention mess up. I understand you cannot paste the whole source, but it would be nice to get the relevant parts pasted, at least.

Comment: Are these three errors the only ones you are getting?

Comment: @n.m. Yes. And there are some warnings, but I think the warnings are not important.

Comment: VS2010 is not listed as a supported platform on the Vray SDK page. It is a very bad idea to mix libraries compiled with different versions of MSC. Try using a supported toolchain.

Comment: @n.m. Then I'll try with VS2008 to solve this problem. If it solves the problem, i'll tell you. Thank you.

Comment: @LaszloPapp As I said above, I don't know which part should I upload here, so I just upload VS project itself. I don't think so this is good way to solve my problem, but I'm too discouraged with this problem so I hope someone can save me.

Comment: @CIMPLE: The part giving the error.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you for your advice! I **succeed** to compile the Vray project with VS2008. I didn't know a version of MSC is very sensitive...  I'm sorry and thank you very much!

Comment: Please take time to answer your question, if you were able to solve it. And accept it.